# Save NSDate and Doubles into Entity (CoreData)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I can get it to work fine using just Strings but if I try to use Doubles or NSDates then I get an error:
"Cannot assign value of type "NSDate?" to type "String?"
"Cannot assign value of type "Double?" to type "String?"

```
@IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {

    if item != nil {

        item?.startdate = startDate.text
        item?.pickup = pickup.text
        item?.miles = miles.text
        item?.company = company.text
        item?.destination = destination.text
        item?.enddate = endDate.text            

    } else {

        let entitydescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Entity", in: pc)

        let item = Entity(entity: entitydescription!, insertInto: pc)

        item.startdate = startDate.text
        item.pickup = pickup.text
        item.miles = miles.text
        item.company = company.text
        item.destination = destination.text
        item.enddate = endDate.text

    }

    do {

        try pc.save()

    } catch {

        print(error)
        return
    }

    navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)

}
```

Here is what type each field is:
    @NSManaged public var startdate: NSDate?
    @NSManaged public var pickup: String?
    @NSManaged public var miles: Double
    @NSManaged public var company: String?
    @NSManaged public var destination: String?
    @NSManaged public var enddate: NSDate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert miles.text, startdate.text and enddate.text to Double, NSDate and NSDate, respectively.

**For startdate.text / enddate.text:**

I'm not sure how what limit you have set for these values when the item is saved, but you should use a default value just incase the conversion fails. For this example, assume the dates are formatted "5/15/17" which takes the format M/d/y

```
let defaultDate = NSDate() //current date
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "M/d/y"

if let startDateText = startdate.text, let startDate = dateFormatter.string(from: startDateText) as? NSDate {
    item?.startdate = startDate
} else { 
    item?.startdate = defaultDate
}

if let endDateText = startdate.text, let endDate = dateFormatter.string(from: endDateText) as? NSDate {
    item?.startdate = endDate
} else { 
    item?.startdate = defaultDate
}
```

**For miles.text:**

Same idea, use a default value incase the conversion failed based on what the text will be for item.miles

```
if let milesText = miles.text {
    item?.miles = Double(miles.text) ?? 0.0 //default is 0.0
} else { 
    item?.miles = 0.0
}
```

or an easy one-liner—

```
item?.miles = Double(miles.text ?? "0.0")
```

if there's a specific default value you have in mind, just declare it before you assign the item's property,

```
let defaultMilesStr = "0.432"
item?.miles = Double(miles.text ?? defaultMiles)
```

Also, just a tip, it's good practice to not leave optionals wrapped when assigning values. So even though there was check to make sure item != nil, it's overall better to safely unwrap item with a "guard" or "if-let". Since you are creating a new item if one doesn't exist, id go with if-let in this case:

```
if let item = item {

  // assign values to item's prop's
  // item.startdate = .....

} else if let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Entity", in: pc), let item = Entity(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: pc) {

  // assign values to item's prop's
  // item.startdate = .....

}

//further execution
```

Comment: Awesome.... Thank you!!!!! I might figure this out eventually..... lol
Only thing I noticed was once I put it in the "if let" this is what it wanted "item.miles = Double(miles.text!) ?? 0.0 // default is 0.0"

Comment: I will fix my answer, but it's the same optional check as the startdate.text and enddate.text: **if let milesText = miles.text ...** or you could make it a one-liner and do: **item?.miles = Double(miles.text ?? "0.0")

Answer (score 0):

Convert your date string to NSdate then you are able to save that

Try this code i have provide my date string you mat change with your format

```
let dateString = "Thu, 22 Oct 2015 07:45:17 +0000"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss +zzzz"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_GB")
let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = /* date_format_you_want_in_string from
                            * http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime
                            */
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: /* your_date_string */)
```

and set it as :

```
item?.date = date
```

For miles you can use :

```
if let dMiles = Double(miles.text!) {
    item?.miles.text = dMiles
} else {
    print("Not a valid Double: \(textField.text!)")
}
```

Hope it Helps!!